# Cross Site Scripting issue on jsp input tag

Tags: jsp, security, servlets, xss

I'm new with Acunetix and XSS issues, so I'm a little lost here.

The thing is, I've a report saying that I've a possibly vulnerable to Cross Site Scripting (XSS) attack in my code.

```
URL encoded POST input chkId_0 was set to 203_908434'():;998649
The input is reflected inside Javascript code between single quotes.
```

In my JSP I've something like this:

```
<%          if (!someCondition) { %>                
            <input class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="chkId_0" value="<%=office.getId()%>" <%=auxDisabled%> />
<%          } else { %>          
            <input class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="chkId_0" value="    <%=office.getId()%>" <%=auxDisabled%> disabled/>
<%          } %>
```

And to mount the url's I'm using `query = request.getQueryString();`, where the value of chkId_0 is attached (?...&chkId_0=203_908434'():;998649&...)

So far, I'm using a filter and overriding getParameter() and getParameterValues() from HttpServletRequestWrapper to avoid some other XSS issues, but no clue how to solve this one.

```
@Override
public String getParameter(String parameter) {
    String value = super.getParameter(parameter);

    return stripXSS(value);
}

private static Pattern[] patterns = new Pattern[]{
    // Script fragments
    Pattern.compile("<script>(.*?)</script>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE),
    // src='...'
    Pattern.compile("src[\r\n]*=[\r\n]*\\\'(.*?)\\\'", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL),
    Pattern.compile("src[\r\n]*=[\r\n]*\\\"(.*?)\\\"", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL),
    // lonely script tags
    Pattern.compile("</script>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE),
    Pattern.compile("<script(.*?)>", Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE | Pattern.MULTILINE | Pattern.DOTALL),
    // eval(...)
    //...
};

public static String stripXSS(String value) {
    if (value != null) {           
        // Avoid null characters
        value = value.replaceAll("\0", "");

        // Remove all sections that match a pattern
        for (Pattern scriptPattern : patterns){
            value = scriptPattern.matcher(value).replaceAll("");
        }
    }
    return value;
}
```

I've read that I could solve this using JSTL ( `<c:out>` ), but unfortunatelly this is not an option to me, as the code is legacy.

Any kind of help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you are printing the ID into the input value I don't see how that is vulnerable to XSS, unless the user can set a arbritary string as an id. But don't try to "strip XSS" using a black list, you are going to have a bad time. Hackers can come up with things you wouldn't even think about, try a white list better if you are going to do it.

Comment: The thing is this parameter goes into the the construction of urls as I'm using the request.getQueryString() to make it.
So, in your opinion, what should I do instead of using a black list method..?
Thanks for your comment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 <input class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="chkId_0" value="<%=office.getId()%>"/>
```

Every text string you drop into a surrounding HTML context *must* be HTML-escaped.

(This is for correctness as well as security: a `"` in the value should appear as a `"` on the page, and not a broken input tag. To achieve this the character `"` has to be written as HTML `&quot;`.)

If you don't have JSP 2.0's c: tags available to do this then you will need a separate escaping function. For example:

```
 <input class="chkbox" type="checkbox" name="chkId_0" value="<%= StringEscapeUtils.escapeHtml4(office.getId()) %>"/>
```

However, looking at the error:

> The input is reflected inside Javascript code between single quotes.

It isn't complaining about HTML-injection but JS-injection. You probably have something like this on the page that receives the form submission:

```
<script>
    var chkId = '<%= request.getParameter("chkId_0") %>';
</script>
```

Here we are inserting text into a JavaScript string literal, so we need to use JS-string-literal-escaping so that if there's a single-quote in the value, it comes out as a JS `\'` escape:

```
<script>
    var chkId = '<%= StringEscapeUtils.escapeEcmaScript(request.getParameter("chkId_0")) %>';
</script>
```

(These examples use [StringEscapeUtils from Apache Commons Lang](https://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/org/apache/commons/lang3/StringEscapeUtils.html), which is unsatisfactory in a number of ways but sufficient for these purposes.)

> I'm using a filter and overriding getParameter() and getParameterValues() from HttpServletRequestWrapper to avoid some other XSS issues

This is completely unworkable. There are dozens of ways around your blacklist patterns. To make this catch all possible attacks you would have to disallow all characters that were special in HTML, JS or any other format you're injecting into—essentially blocking all punctuation, which is rarely acceptable.

Instead concentrate on using the correct form of escaping at the output end.

Comment: So you're saying that I'm not doing a good approach to solve my problem, using filters and blacklist patterns, but what would be the correct solution? Any piece of advice? Thanks for your answer.